# SQL syntax error upon server update; cannot execute query

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY lastname ASC' at line 1

suddenly on a webpage that interfaces with a MySQL database. We recently had the MySQL server updated.

I checked the other threads on this but it doesn't appear we break anything.

The relevant code which makes the error (I think) is

```
query = 'SELECT myTable.*, place.placeID 
         FROM myDatabase 
            LEFT JOIN place ON myDatabase.placeID=place.placeID 
        WHERE myTableID IN ('.implode(', ',array_fill(0,count($myTableIDs),'?')).') 
        ORDER BY '.$orderby.' '.$direction.';';
```

The orderby and direction strings are defined previously as

```
    $orderby = 'lastname';
    $direction = 'ASC';
```

Then we execute this query.

Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: Why not echo the query that is created, and have a look at it or post it here. I think `count($myTableIDs)` could be zero?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think you're right. The table count is empty.

SELECT myTable.*,place.placeID,FROM people LEFT JOIN place ON myTable.placeID=place.placeID WHERE myTable IN () ORDER BY lastname ASC;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what code you are using to generate the query, but I'd put the equivalent of "print $query" to find out what is going to SQL; then work from there, check the syntax looks correct, and trying to insert the generated SQL into an SQL browser (if you have one).

Comment: This is only a comment and you have more than enough reps to make a comment!  Please dont put comments in an Answer